# Reset Session on redirect to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am working on a contract management web application. I want to clear all my session variables when user change the page. For example suppose the current page of user is "Default.aspx" and I create 3 session variables on this page when the user changes the page to "Profile.aspx" 3 session variables should be removed.

Please notice: I am using ASP.NET.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
Session.RemoveAll (); //Removes all session variables. Just calls the  Session.Clear() method in its implementation, so for ease you can say there is no difference.
```

OR

```
Session.Abandon(); //Releases sessionstate itself to be garbage collected when chance arrives. Only point to note that it happens just before the current request is fulfilled.
```

OR

```
Session.Clear(); //Releases all key value pairs immideatly and make them available for garbage collection. But the Resource used by SessionState Collection are intact and booked as is.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that in **Page_Load** of Profile.aspx:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   Session.Clear();
}
```